# limit scope of search webpart to site sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, search-results, scope

I just created a search page for a proposal archive site we have. I noticed that when I search it finds me results from the parent site as well.

Is there a way to limit the scope of the search to be just the site that it is in

Answer (score 4):

One of the options would be to configure properties of the Search Results web part.

### How to limit search scope via Search Results web part

- Open search results page in Edit mode
- In the Search Results Web Part, click the Search Results Web Part
  Menu arrow, and then click Edit Web Part
- In the Web Part tool pane, in the `Search Criteria` section, click
  `Change query`
- In Property Filter, select property named `Path` and specify value
  `This site`, then click `Add property filter` button (the generated query is shown on figure below)

[image]

### References

[Configure properties of the Search Results Web Part in SharePoint Server 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg549987%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: I will give this a try on Tuesday (when im back to work) thanks so much

Comment: I gave this a try and it will only comeback with one result which is for the site url of the site it is in. It does not search through the contents of just the site anymore. any thoughts?